# Zomei z669 compatability to Acra-swiss connection

Tags: tripod

I have Sony a6500 camera and I had like to buy the following:

1) L bracket

2) Zomei z669 tripod

The L bracket is Acra-swiss connection however I cant find if the Zomei z669 supports it.

If someone owns/knows it can help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the various pictures of Zomei tripods on Amazon their quick-release plate is the Arca-Swiss type.

Comment: Thank you mate!

Comment: Not all "Arca-Swiss" type plates are compatible with all "Arca-Swiss" type clamps. There is no real standard. Please see: [Is a 50mm-wide arca-mount a standard?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/79382/15871) and [ARCA-SWISS IS NOT A STANDARD, TIME FOR A CHANGE](https://www.jobu-design.com/Arca-Swiss-is-NOT-a-standard-time-for-a-change_b_8.html)

Answer (score 3):

I have seen more than a few heads that *appear to be* arca swiss compatible, but they aren't because they don't open nearly wide enough. 
Actually, there is no single arca swiss standard; so even one stated to be "arca swiss compatible" isn't a 100% guarantee.

But it does look like this one is pretty compatible...

[image]